# What's with the Paladin's ranged powers? Do they provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, paladin

So I am a little bit confused.

I am currently playing a Paladin built for tanking and holding the front while my party hopefully finishes the enemy off before I die.

I was looking though some of the later abilities and noticed that there are several ranged implement abilities in there such as Beckon Foe and Radiant Pulse. This I find odd since Paladins are supposed to be up in the thick of things and ranged attacks provoke opportunity attacks.

Am I wrong in assuming that these abilities provoke attacks from enemies around me? If they do, would that not essentially be pretty useless for defensive orientated Paladins? Or do Paladin implements somehow work differently and allow you not to take a axe to the face while you pull an enemy off your ally that is about to die?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unfortunately, ranged paladin attacks do provoke<sup>1</sup>.**

Paladins are designed to be in-your-face glowy shiny people. Unfortunately, the enemy sometimes decides that they simply don't want to *bother* with Mr. Shiny, and, as such, provision has been made for the paladin to "take the enemy to the fight."

Or the paladin could have the quite reasonable [Mighty Crusader Expertise](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3742) (Dragon 402), and smile so broadly that, indeed, his ranged prayers don't provoke (which leads to some fascinating builds like my hand of radiance half-elf paladin.)

<sup>1</sup>Some exceptions apply, not valid with all feats.

Comment: Mighty Crusader Expertise is a must if you plan on a Pally build that uses holy symbol powers.